# I get an ERROR subquery must return only one column. How do I solve this?

Tags: sql, subquery, nested-function

```
select count(distinct "WorkContracts"."SubstituteTeacher") as "Count", "Accounts"."FirstName", "Accounts"."LastName", "Candidates"."Confirmed", "Candidates"."FinalStatus"
from dbo."Accounts"
left join dbo."WorkContracts" on "Accounts"."ID" = "WorkContracts"."SubstituteTeacher" 
full outer join dbo."SubstituteTeacherPeriods" on "Accounts"."ID" = "SubstituteTeacherPeriods"."CreatedBy" 
full outer join dbo."Candidates" ON "Accounts"."ID" = "Candidates"."ModifiedBy" 
where "WorkContracts"."WorkContractType" != 3 
and "SubstituteTeacherPeriods"."StartTime" > TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-18 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') 
and "SubstituteTeacherPeriods"."EndTime" < TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-19 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') 
and "SubstituteTeacherPeriods"."Discriminator" = 'AvailabilityPeriod'
and "Candidates"."FinalStatus" = (select max("FinalStatus") from dbo."Candidates")
and "Candidates"."Confirmed"= (select max("Confirmed")"Confirmed", "SubstituteTeacher" from dbo."Candidates" group by "SubstituteTeacher")
group by "Accounts"."FirstName", "Accounts"."LastName", "Candidates"."FinalStatus", "Candidates"."Confirmed"
```

Comment: Those conditions in the WHERE clause make outer joins return inner join result. Move to ON clause to get true outer join result.

Comment: Simplify your query to solve the problem. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Line 11 is causing the error as you are saying that 1 column ("Candidates"."Confirmed") equals to 2 columns (max("Confirmed")"Confirmed", "SubstituteTeacher") - which are selected from the sub-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the line causing the error:

```
and "Candidates"."Confirmed" = (select max("Confirmed")"Confirmed", "SubstituteTeacher"
    from dbo."Candidates" group by "SubstituteTeacher")
```

First of all, it doesn't make sense to compare a single scalar value to a record having *two* values.  But, worse than this, the subquery on the RHS is probably returning more than one record.  Try changing to this:

```
AND "Candidates"."Confirmed" IN (SELECT MAX("Confirmed") FROM dbo."Candidates"
                                 GROUP BY "SubstituteTeacher")
```

Here is your entire query refactored with this problem fixed:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT wc.SubstituteTeacher) AS Count,
    a.FirstName,
    a.LastName,
    c.Confirmed,
    c.FinalStatus
FROM dbo.Accounts a
LEFT JOIN dbo.WorkContracts wc
    ON a.ID = wc.SubstituteTeacher
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.SubstituteTeacherPeriods s
    ON a.ID = s.CreatedBy
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Candidates c
    ON a.ID = c.ModifiedBy
WHERE
    wc.WorkContractType != 3 AND
    s.StartTime >= '2018-09-18 00:00:00' AND s.EndTime < '2018-09-19 00:00:00' AND
    s.Discriminator = 'AvailabilityPeriod' AND
    c.FinalStatus = (SELECT MAX(FinalStatus) FROM dbo.Candidates) AND
    c.Confirmed IN (SELECT MAX(Confirmed) FROM dbo.Candidates
                             GROUP BY SubstituteTeacher)
GROUP BY
    a.FirstName,
    a.LastName,
    c.FinalStatus,
    c.Confirmed;
```

Note that by introducing table aliases and removing the unnecessary double quotes everywhere, the query becomes much more readable.

If you want the latest record for each teacher using the `Confirmed` column then we can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT wc.SubstituteTeacher) AS Count,
        a.FirstName,
        a.LastName,
        c.Confirmed,
        c.FinalStatus,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.FirstName, a.LastName ORDER BY Confirmed DESC) rn
    FROM dbo.Accounts a
    ...         -- the rest of the above query
)

SELECT
    Count,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Confirmed,
    FinalStatus
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This solves the problem, Thanks. But now the result returns multiple entries for a given substitute teacher, whereas I would like to see the last entry for each. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which column denotes what is "last?"  I can't really edit my question without seeing some data.  It would be good for you to paste a link to a running demo with data.  Then I can try to fix this additional problem.

Comment: Each time a Substitute Teacher gets an assignment a date and timestamp is created under the Confirmed column. A teacher can get multiple assignments during a given time period so I would like to know the latest record of confirmed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Should be probably a Correlated Subquery instead of IN.

Comment: @dnoeth The problem with questions like these is that often, even after fixing the original problem, more problems immediately come up.